# Symfony Pdfbundle not working

Tags: php, symfony

When trying to use pdfBundle with symfony I get the following error, all i've done so far is installed pdfbundle via symfony and registered it in app.php.

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Silex\Application::register() must implement interface Silex\ServiceProviderInterface, instance of Ps\PdfBundle\PsPdfBundle given, called in C:\wamp\www\computername\Project1\app\bootstrap.php on line 20 and defined in C:\wamp\www\computername\Project1\vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\Application.php on line 165
```

My composer file looks like this:

```
{
"require": {
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "components/jquery": "2.1.0",
    "twig/twig": "1.18.0",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.3.*",
    "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/repository-service-provider": "dev-master",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Defensie": "src/"
    }
}
```

}

App.php:

```
....
$app->register(new Ps\PdfBundle\PsPdfBundle());
....
```

If there's more information you need, go ahead and ask.

Answer (score 1):

> trying to use pdfBundle with symfony

First of all that it looks like you are using Silex that is micro-framework based on Symfony2.

So you try to use Symfony2 bundle, but register it as Silex service provider.

```
$app->register(new Ps\PdfBundle\PsPdfBundle());
```

You can't just connect 3rd party bundles from Symfony2 with Silex. Silex uses  a "ServiceProviderInterface" to connect 3rd party bundles. http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers.html

```
interface ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Application $app);

    public function boot(Application $app);
}
```

So either a bundle should have already implemented service provider to integrate it to Silex or you must to implement it self to connect 3rd party lib. Here is some example how to create service provider to integrate Buzz client  http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/02/silex-creating-a-service-provider-for-buzz/